# passing on value to partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am trying to pass in my model to a partial view. When it is passed in I would like to set the value of the argument. When I run this i get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of the object
```

How can it say that because I passed in this Model?

```
@using passTextbox.Models
@model passTextbox.Models.MyViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.someobject)

@{ Html.RenderAction("test", new MyViewModel() { someobject = "$('#somevalue')" });}

 public class MyViewModel
 {
        public string someobject { get; set; }
 }
```

partialview:

```
@model passTextbox.Models.MyViewModel
<h2>test</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tb = @Model.somevalue;
        tb.val("new value");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Html.RenderPartial` instad of `Html.RenderAction`

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string someObject { get; set; }
    }
```

In the View

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("partial", new MvcApplication1.Controllers.MyViewModel() { someObject = "test" });}
```

and finally in the Partial view

```
 @model MyViewModel

<h2>test</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tb ="@Model.someObject";
        alert(tb);
    });
</script>
```